# Codeigniter - Create Link "View All" pagination

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

how to create link "view all" on page with pagination.

Exc: i have category for 20 results default then i need create link button for "view all" how to do that?

Step By Step Please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue is not codeigniter feature. You can adjust your code to show all records.

Add following link to your code

```
<a href="your_page_url?all=1">View All</a>
```

Change your controller if all request is available.

```
$allRows = getAllRows();

if ($this->input->get() !== FALSE) {
    $all = $this->input->get(all);
}    

if ($all == 1) {
   $data['rows'] = $allRows;
} else {
   $this->load->library('pagination');

   $config = $pageSize;
   $this->pagination->initialize($config);
   $data['rows'] = array_slice($allRwos, $page, $pageSize);
}
```

Comment: where to put link a href and where i must put script in controller?

Answer (score 0):

1-In your viewAll link you can call a function that get all the data from database
with out limit and display it on the page.

2-If you are good in jquery-ajax you can make this dynamic linke when you clicked the showAll
all the records will be shown and the name should be changed to view with limits.